# Are changes in a point release applied progressively to a released version before it comes out

Tags: 12.04, updates, release-management

(Note that I think the title can receive a change to better explain what I am asking here)

I have installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04. I noticed that the 12.04.1 will come soon and was wondering if the updates that 12.04.1 will bring are applied to 12.04 progressively until 12.04.1 comes out or are they applied all at the same time when 12.04.1 comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point release essentially contains the bug fixes the version has gone since it was released to the public, which includes security fixes, package updates, translation packs updates, etc.

These point releases will include support for new hardware as well as rolling up all the updates published in that series to date. So a fresh install of a point release will work on newer hardware and will also not require a big download of additional updates. --Mark Shuttleworth [this may be dated back but still holds true](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/146)

If you update frequently you will essentially be at the "point release" as soon as the general release is made available.

Comment: It's worth noting that the hardware enablement part of the point release comes in the form of new kernel packages. You won't automatically be upgraded to those, if you are already running precise (because you clearly don't *need* to be).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are applied progressively, in fact, if you install regular updates, there won't be much to do when 12.04.1 gets out. You'll see the number changed in `/etc/lsb-release`, and that's about it. Point releases are really about getting the ISOs updated.